# Empirical distribution vs. the true one: How fast $KL( \hat{P}_n || Q)$ converges to $KL( P || Q)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, reference-request, information-theory, learning

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be i.i.d. samples drawn from a discrete space $\mathcal{X}$ according to probability distribution $P$, and denote the resulting empirical distribution based on n samples by $\hat{P}_n$. Also let $Q$ be an arbitrary distribution. It is clear that (KL-divergence)

\begin{equation} 
    KL( \hat{P}_n || Q) \stackrel{n\rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} KL(P || Q)
\end{equation}

but I am wondering if there exist any known quantitative rate of convergence for it. I mean if it can be shown that

\begin{equation}
    \Pr\Big[ | KL( \hat{P}_n || Q) - KL(P || Q) | \geq \delta\Big] \leq f(\delta, n, |\mathcal{X}|)
\end{equation}

and what is the best expression for the RHS if there is any.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just to clarify: You're asking for a uniform bound in $P$ and $Q$?

Comment: @cardinal: Yes. In fact I want to know how many samples should I take to guarantee a maximum gap for the KL-divergence. Note that $n$ can be much larger that $|\mathcal{X}|$, i.e. $\hat{P}_n$ closely follow the true $P$.

Comment: I am wondering whether (or how) $D(\hat{P_n}\|P)\to 0$ is different from $D(\hat{P_n}\|Q)\to D(P\|Q)$.

Comment: @Ashok: The KL-divergence is not a _true_ metric (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence). In particular, the triangle inequality does NOT hold, and $D(\hat{P}_n\| Q)−D(P \| Q)$ can be larger than $D(\hat{P}_n \| P)$. Hence, even if $D(\hat{P}_n\| P)\rightarrow 0$ implies $ D(\hat{P}_n \| Q)\rightarrow D(P\| Q)$ (does it?), the convergence rate of the former does not guarantee the convergence rate for the latter.

Comment: @Sam: Yes,yes, you are right. I know KL-divergence is not a metric. But I just wanted to know the difference between $D(\hat{P}_n\| P)\rightarrow 0$ and $D(\hat{P_n}\|Q)\to D(P\|Q)$. I am also very interested in your question.

Comment: Sam, I had hoped to get back to looking at this question a bit more closely, but am very tied up at the moment, so I thought I'd at least suggest in the interim that you look at Liam Paninski's work on estimating entropy and mutual information. I recall some very strong *negative* results for such questions for arbitrary entropy estimators.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a thought. I don't know whether I am in an imaginary world and asking too much. Any way, let me propose this. I am writing it as an answer as it is little larger to put it as a comment.

Suppose, for every fixed $Q$, we can find a linear family $\Pi$ of prob. distributions consisting of all empirical measures $\hat{P_n}$ and $P$, and such that $P$ is the $I$-projection of $Q$ on $\Pi$, then the Pythagorean property $$D(\hat{P_n}\| Q)=D(\hat{P_n}\|P)+D(P \| Q)$$
holds and hence the convergence rate of $D(\hat{P}_n\| Q)\to D(P \| Q)$ is same as that of $D(\hat{P}_n\| P)\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

This is addressed in

> Rohit Agrawal. Multinomial concentration in relative entropy at the ratio of alphabet and sample sizes. CoRR, [abs/1904.02291](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.02291)

See, e.g., Theorem 8 in [this short note of mine](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.11457).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the last answer, the most popular concentration inequality for the KL divergence is for finite alphabets. You can look for Theo. 11.2.1 of "Elements of Information Theory" by Thomas Cover and Joy Thomas:
$$\mathbf{P}\left(D(\hat{P}_n\|P)\geq\epsilon\right)\leq e^{-n\left(\epsilon-|\mathcal{X}|\frac{\log(n+1)}{}n\right)}$$